# Julia function with NULL argument

Tags: r, julia

In R you can use NULL arguments in functions like 
    myfun = function (a=NULL, b, c)
can you do this in Julia? I'm asking because I'd like variable a as a condition : if a = NULL do this, else do that. I can just write different functions of course but they would mostly repeat each other. I can also just assign arbitrary numbers but it seems using NULL is more clear. Thanks!.

Comment: Perhaps you need `Nullable{Int64}()` if it is a integer64

Comment: what from the documentation wasn't clear? https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/
-and- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751541/none-value-in-julia
-and-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499528/julia-convention-for-optional-arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia convention for optional arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42499528/julia-convention-for-optional-arguments)

Comment: The equivalent of `NULL` is `nothing`, of type `Nothing`. If you can, it's better to avoid it in function arguments, but at times it's fine. It's a subtle issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the most common questions from people coming to a new language is how to code exactly like in the language they come from. But testing for NULL is not likely to be the best way to implement this in Julia. Mostly you'll define two methods for your function:

```
function myfun(a, b, c)
    ...
end

function myfun(b, c)
    ...
end
```

With the different behaviours.