# Julia: function with optional argument of type Vector but default to null?

Tags: function, null, arguments, julia, default

I have a function `f(x)`. I would like that function to have an optional parameter of type vector. For instance, `f(x; y::Vector=[1,2,3])`. However, I'd like the default value to be something else (null? missing? void?) so that I can easily catch it and react to it.

In R, I would say `function(x, y=NULL){}` and then `if(is.null(y)){whatever}`.

What would be the most julian way of doing something similar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia function with NULL argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628523/julia-function-with-null-argument)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pattern referenced in the comment by Engineero is cleanest, but it assumes a positional argument. If you insist on having a keyword argument (as you do in your question) to your function use:

```
function f(x; y::Union{Vector, Nothing}=nothing)
    if y === nothing
        # do something
    else
        # do something else
    end
end
```

This is usually needed only if you have a lot of keyword arguments, as otherwise I would recommend defining methods with different positional parameter signatures.

Of course it is fully OK to use this pattern with `nothing` also for positional arguments if you find it preferable.

Comment: dammit ... every time I check this language everything has changed again ... what happened to Nullable??

Comment: It is moved out to Nullables.jl package. In short: now you have `nothing` that is a singleton instance of `Nothing` and due to Julia 1.0 improvements the recommended style is to use union types like `Union{Int, Nothing}` and then `nothing` indicates absence of the value (and thus sometimes you have to use `Some` type to distinguish between absence of the value and situation where `nothing` is a valid value).

Comment: Also worth noting that the code in your solution should be fast due to union splitting optimisation in more recent versions: https://julialang.org/blog/2018/08/union-splitting